# ATI OpenCL printf extension issue with char* argument passed to a function

Tags: printf, opencl, ati

I use OpenCL on an ATI card with the printf extension enabled. I've written a function to print out variables:

```
void printVar(constant char* name, float var)
{
    printf("%s: %f\r\n", name, var);
}
```

This code works as expected when compiled as plain C, but if i invoke it in OpenCL with

```
printVar("foo", 0.123);
```

the result is always some random char followed by 0.123 instead of "foo: 0.123". I guess the compiler has problems with recognizing the char* string, is there a workaround or a fix so i can get the function working?

Comment: I also get this behavior. Notably it works as expected if the kernel is run on my CPU (with AMD APP SDK 2.3), but not on my HD 5870. I guess it's either a bug or an undocumented limitation of printf on the GPU.

Comment: For completeness: I've just read the AMD APP SDK 2.4 developer release notes, and they state that printf does not currently support printing strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment I also get the same behavior, however I can suggest a simple workaround for the use case you showed, I.e. when the string is known at compile time we could just use a define statement instead:

```
#define PRINTVAR(N,X) (printf(N ": %f\r\n", X))
```